# Initialize a user-defined variable through mysql console parameters

Tags: mysql

I would like to pass a value of a user-defined parameter to mysql console and use it as following:

**example.sql**:

```
    SELECT (@somevar + 1) as my_sum;
```

**usage example**:

```
C:>bin\mysql -utest -p --xml **{somehow @somevar:=100}** < example.sql
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<resultset statement="SELECT (@somevar + 1) as my_sum"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <row>
        <field name="my_sum" xsi:nil="true" />
    </row>
</resultset>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C:>bin\mysql --init-command="SET @somevar:=100"

mysql> select @somevar;
+----------+
| @somevar |
+----------+
|      100 |
+----------+
```

---

Re your comment:

Yes, it's odd that it's not documented.  But you can see it with `mysql --help`.  You can also try it like I did, and see that it works.

I have logged a bug to ask for this option to be added to the manual.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63672

Comment: hmm, MySQL does not seem to have the `--init-command` option (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html)

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I actually use mysql 5.1 which lacks the option, so I went with the solution I mentioned below. But your solution is more natural and correct. I reaccept your answer =) thank you once again.

Comment: Yeah it seems this feature is still not thought through very well even in 5.5, because it works on the command-line, but not in the `[client]` section of a .cnf file.  There's a bug open for that too.  I hope they fix it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
c:\bin>set somevar=1
c:\bin>mysql -e "select %a%+1 as my_sum"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that came to my mind (just for reference):

```
C:>bin\mysql -utest -p --xml -e "SET @somevar:=100; source example.sql;"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<resultset statement="SELECT (@somevar + 1) as my_sum"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <row>
        <field name="my_sum">101</field>
    </row>
</resultset>
```